# Segmentation Fault while simulating top-down addition in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, addition

I'm trying to write a program in C++ that takes in two strings containing numbers and adds them together to return a "sum" (which is also a string).
I've written comparable programs in Java and Python, so I decided that while learning C++, I might as well write something comparable.  I don't know why I'm receiving the errors, and I'm not receiving any errors while compiling with Visual Studio or g++.

Below is the reference to the function in question in the main program.

```
Number base(NULL);
Number r = base.addNums("1", "1");
cout << r.toString() << endl;
```

I have ensured that I have a constructor as follows for the reference to the addNums function:

```
Number(void){}
```

I wrote some comments to try and explain my thought process while writing the header file.  The method in question is as follows:

```
Number addNums(string in1, string in2){
        // Calling number 1: X, and number 2: Y
        const char* x;
        const char* y;
        x = in1.c_str();
        y = in2.c_str();

        // Flag for one number having more digits
        bool flag = false;
        // Flag for X having more digits
        bool xIsBigger = false;
        // For storing the sum later
        string summ = "";

        // Check and see if the flags are needed
        if (!(strlen(x) == strlen(y))){
            flag = true;
            if (strlen(x) > strlen(y)){
                xIsBigger = true;
            }
        }

        // Prepend the zeroes to the necessary variable
        //   to make it work as written addition does
        if (flag){
            if (xIsBigger){
                string zeroes;
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (strlen(x) - strlen(y)); ++i){
                    zeroes += "0";
                }
                string newYStr = zeroes + in2;
                const char* newY = newYStr.c_str();
                // Add zeroes to Y variable
                y = newY;
            } else{
                string zeroes;
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (strlen(y) - strlen(x)); ++i){
                    zeroes += "0";
                }
                string newXStr = zeroes + in1;
                const char* newX = newXStr.c_str();
                // Add variables to X value
                x = newX;
            }
        }

        // If we encounter x + y > 9, we need this
        int carry = 0;
        // Current digit being processed
        char digitX, digitY;
        // Digit to be carried
        char toCarry;

        // Iterate through the number right to left
        //   to simulate top-down addition
        for (int i = strlen(x) - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            digitX = x[i];
            digitY = y[i];

            // If we're carrying a 1, add it to the top number
            if (carry > 0){
                digitX += 1;
                carry = 0;
            }

            // Add together the two numbers stored in characters
            int currentSum = atoi(&digitX) + atoi(&digitY);

            // If x + y > 9, we need to carry
            if (currentSum > 9){
                string sumString = "" + currentSum;
                // Max possible is 9 + 9, so we only have to carry 1
                carry = 1;
                // Add the second digit in the number to the position in the sum
                summ = sumString.at(1) + summ;
            }
            // Didn't need a carry
            else{
                string sumString = "" + currentSum;
                summ = sumString + summ;
            }
        }
        // Return the object containing the sum
        return Number(summ);
    }
```

I'm relatively new to the use of pointers, but in the process of learning some more of the language and writing this program, and through extensive googling of syntax and language-specifics, I've been forced into what I feel is the need to use them.

I'm very sorry I cannot provide more information and I appreciate any help or critique that can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should not be tagged as `C`, IMHO.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't catch that I tagged it as C  as well.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be using pointers in this program. What exactly makes you think you need them?

Comment: Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `strlen` on `std::string.c_str()` is all sorts of wrong.  Strings have a size function, use it.

Comment: @n.m. Assignments of strings to character arrays are the reason I've used them.
I figured the referencing of the pointers is the issue.

Comment: @Beta
I will try to get it cleaned up and look more into it in the morning.  I'm sorry for the mess.

Comment: @RetiredNinja:
Thanks for the tip!  I'll work that into the new minimal complete example in the morning.
Sorry for the mess!

Comment: You don't need arrays either. The string type has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

'string newYStr' may be going out of scope? Try declaring it in the top and then check.